# Cannot connect to SQL SERVER 2000 with php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Cannot connect to SQL SERVER 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467286/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-2000)

I am using php 5.3.1 to connect to my SQL SERVER 2000 on remote machine. I use Windows XP.
On using simple program like this:

```
$conn = mssql_connect("VBNET","sa","anythinghere") or die ( 'Can not connect to server' );
```

I get following error:

> Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: message: Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection. (severity 14) in C:\wamp\www\Mssql\test.php on line 8
>
> Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: VBNET in C:\wamp\www\Mssql\test.php on line 8
> Can not connect to server

I enabled TCP/IP and named pipes in my SQL SERVER and restarted it. Also its Authentication is set to Mixed Mode Authentication. So what am I missing here ?

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT*** This question was first about SQL SERVER 2008 but later it was brought to my knowledge that it was SQL SERVER 2000. Forgive me for my ignorance but the problem still exists. So please give me suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **This problem occurs when the SQL Serversecurity authentication is set
> to Windows only, and one of the following conditions is true**:
>
> - You are trying to connect to a SQL Server database with a SQL Server    login.
> - You are trying to connect to a SQL Server 2000 Desktop Engine (also    known as MSDE 2000) database that is installed on a Microsoft Windows
>   98-based computer by using a trusted SQL Server connection.
> - You are trying to connect to a SQL Server database from a Windows    account that does not have sufficient permissions to connect to the
>   server.
>
> **To work around this problem, use one of the following methods depending on the symptom that you are experiencing:**
>
> **- A SQL Server login**
>
> Use a valid Windows login to connect to SQL Server. If you must
> continue to use a SQL Server login, you can change the security
> authentication mode in SQL Server to SQL Server and Windows. To do
> this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Start Enterprise Manager.
> 2. Expand Microsoft SQL Servers, and then expand SQL Server Group.
> 3. Right-click the server that you want to change to SQL Server and
>    Windows authentication, and then click Properties.
> 4. In the SQL Server Properties dialog box, click the Security tab,
>    click SQL Server and Windows, and then click OK.
> 5. When you are prompted to re-start the SQL Server service, click Yes.
>
> **- A Windows account with insufficient permissions**
>
> To work around this problem, you must add the Windows account to SQL
> Server, and then grant the appropriate permissions to each database
> that the user requires access to. To do this in SQL Server 2000,
> follow these steps:
>
> 1. Start Enterprise Manager.
> 2. Expand Microsoft SQL Server, and then expand SQL Server Group.
> 3. Expand your server, and then expand Security.
> 4. Right-click Logins, and then click New Login.
> 5. In the SQL Server Login Properties dialog box, enter the Windows
>    account name in the Name box. In the Domain list, select the domain
>    that the Windows account is a member of.
> 6. Click the Database Access tab, set the appropriate permissions for
>    the client, and then click OK.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889615

Comment: @hermann-Our Server mode is set to Mix Mode Authentication and I am being provided sufficient permissions...so what can be the problem ??

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid have you found a solution to your problem? Try playing around with this setting. Try setting it to Server Authentication only ( if there is such a thing ).

Comment: @hermann-I recently found that my Server is in fact SQL SERVER 2000 instead of 2008..so can that be the problem ? If yes than what can be the solution ??

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid is 'sa' a SQL or Windows account login?

Comment: @hermann *sa* is the default super-administrator, SQL Server user that is installed. (That is; unless the OP did something specifically to change things, it's a SQL login)

Comment: @hermann-sa is the UserName given to me, which works in SSMS...please refer this--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467286/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-2000

Answer (score 2):

Please look at Microsoft knowledge base article [889615](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889615) for the solution. I found this doing a Google search for your error message: "associated with a trusted SQL Server connection".

Comment: @Dalyn-Our Server mode is set to Mix Mode Authentication and I am being provided sufficient permissions...so what can be the problem ??

Comment: Please see the possible duplicate question that is linked to this one and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: @Dalyn-That is asked by me and I voted for the Exact Duplicate part...but thanks for all help..I resolved the issue!!